# Can you create an alert for Azure SQL Database only to alert during specific week days and time of day?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Does not seem like there is an option to add condition that can be used as a filter just for days and time of day such as only alert Monday - Friday 9am - 5pm. Also, does not seem like there is an option for Action Group as well to do something like this. Do we need to use Event Hub or some other method? [image]

Answer (score 0):

As of now there is no direct approach to create alerts for only weekdays. You can try creating an action group and choosing logic app as action. Below are steps I followed,

1. Created logic app as shown below,
   [image]
2. In Trigger added conditions to trigger only on weekdays as shown below,

```
@not(equals(dayOfWeek(utcNow()),6))
@not(equals(dayOfWeek(utcNow()),0))
```

Click on Setting for trigger and add above two in Trigger conditions.
[image]
3. Created action group and configured the created logic app in actions section,
[image]

Reference [link](https://tomriha.com/how-to-schedule-a-power-automate-flow-to-run-only-on-work-days/#:%7E:text=Each%20time%20the%20flow%20will%20trigger%20it%E2%80%99ll%20check,to%20run%20daily%20will%20skip%20Saturdays%20and%20Sundays.)